# Python 3 read csv and keep most recent duplicates

Tags: csv, python-3.x, duplicates

I have a csv file that I am trying to remove rows with duplicate email address from. If the email address is a duplicate I want to keep the row with the highest ID.

```
id  email   _website    _store  confirmation
11  test@abc.com    base    default 1
12  test2@abc.com   base    default 1
13  test@abc.com    base    default 1
```

I have been able to print out a list of the duplicates with the scrip below, but I need to write to a csv with the most recent ID.

```
for row in csv_f:
    if row[1] not in seen:
        seen.add(row[1])
    else:
        if (row[1] > ''):
            pprint.pprint (row[1])
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Are you trying to write to a CSV-File? If so, the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/csv.html#csv.writer) might be helpful. :)

Comment: Yes I want to write to a CSV, but I know how to do that. I am having trouble writing the rows I want to write. I would like to identify that test@abc.com is a duplicate email and only write the one with the highest ID.

Answer (score 0):

You can't write the "latest" without reading all the items in the file. Because the last line might contain an update.

So you'll have to read them all and either identify which ones to delete, or identify which ones to keep. Here's a *keep* approach:

```
seen = {}
EMAIL=1
user_list = []

for user in csv_f:
    seen[user[EMAIL]] = len(user_list)    # index of next .append
    user_list.append(user)

for n,user in enumerate(user_list):
    if seen[user[EMAIL]] == n:
        output(user)                      # Write it, print it, whatever
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to [Austin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35665050/2395605) I would suggest the *overwrite* approach:

```
d = {}   # mail: row
for row in sorted(csv_f):   # should be sorted by the first field (aka ID)
    d[row[1]] = row
pprint.pprint(d.values())
```

Here, the email is used as a key and upcoming rows with the same key just override the stored row. As it is sorted by the ID, the last override has to be the one with the highest ID for that email-address.

A one-liner would be `v = {r[1]: r for r in sorted(csv_f)}.values()`.

You might want to sort the result again, as of the nature of a dictionary the values can appear in arbitrary order.

*Not tested though!*